# Value from datatable to String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, datatable

I got a value from table:

```
zs_code  zs_name
   a      James
   b      John
   c      Mikael
```

i want to convert the zs_name column to one string to be like below:

```
["James", "Mikael", "John"]
```

mean the string value is like above.

may anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim items = String.Join(",", yourTable.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("zs_name")))
Dim result = String.Format("[{0}]", items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
string[] arr = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
 arr[i] = dt.Rows[i]["zs_name"].ToString();
}
```

Source : [this link](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/444465/Store-DataTable-Column-Values-in-String-Array-using-C-Net/)

Happy coding!!!